# I want to bake all my seperate UV maps into a single one to import as a texture into a game but they all overlap

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

[image]

I need to get all the images/UV maps of objects such as the face,eyes,clothes, etc baked into a single image in order for the model to have texture in a game called Table Top Simulator. Whenever I try to bake all the images into a single UV map, they all overlap. I tried doing the smart map and it makes them all fit but it scales them all down and baking carries over no color and looks extremely dark and splotchy.

Comment: How do you want to fit UVs into the space of the texture without scaling them so they do fit? That makes no sense.

Comment: I guess your problem is that the UVs overlap and you need to unwrap correctly? Not sure why the Smart UV Project doesn't work though...